# How do I remove header view? Or fix this exception: "Cannot add header view to list - setAdapter has already been called"

Tags: java, android, header, adapter

I am making a search app where you enter a term, and a list (ListView) of results comes up, with a header that labels the list. You can do another search and get a different set of results. Or you can select one of the results and it takes you to another Activity with a ListView of details for that selection. This all works fine.

But when you go back from the details Activity to the search Activity and type in another search term, I getting the following error.

```
Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
```

Both of my Activity classes have a line like

```
adapter.setAdapter(results);
```

and to my understanding, that is not allowed. My approach to fixing this would be to remove/clear the offending data (would that be the view? list? adapter?) in the onDestroy() of the details activity. But I don't know how to go about doing that, or if that's even the right solution.

Comment: Where is your result built and passed to adapter? onCreate?

Comment: I think search activity doesn't get destroyed when you go to the Details activity, it's paused, when you get back it's resumed. So try to put adapter reset logic in onResume. To reset adapter with new result.

Comment: @Maxim It happens in my "drawTable" function. I don't any part of the table or header to show until after the "Search" button is pressed. That's probably bad though, isn't it... Good point about putting the reset in onResume. But how do I actually reset it?

Comment: Nevermind, every search will give its own result and adapter is gonna be reset in onClickListener not in on resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception clearly states, you had already set the adapter for the `ListView`, and now trying to add a header view to the `ListView`.

As I understand, you need to add the header view only once, but change only the text/data displayed by the header view for each search result (by changing the data in the adapter). You can reframe your code accordingly.